# Place text before and inside fields in contact form 7 for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I am trying to figure out how to put the text before a text field in the WordPress plugin Contact form 7. How can I do that?

I managed to put it inside the field by adding this:

`[text your-name placeholder "Your name here"]`

However, how do I change the color of the text inside to be a certain color?

Answer (score 1):

The Contact Form 7 editor accepts HTML. You can get the text above the inputs by doing something similar to the following:

```
<p>
    <label>Your Name</label>
    [text* your-name] 
</p>

<p>
    <label>Your Email</label>
    [email* your-email]
</p>

<p>
    <label>Your Message</label>
    [textarea your-message]
</p>

<p>
    [submit "Send"]
</p>
```

I believe the second part of your question involves changing the placeholder color text. This doesn't have great support but can be done by doing the following.

```
<style>
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the label text to be on the left side of the box, not above. Sorry for not being clear.

Where should I put the last code you wrote? I tried in Custom CSS but it does not work.

Comment: This worked for me: 

Use the ::placeholder https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/